# Python dict / list assignment [] = () is valid but not () = []

Tags: python

In python 3.5.5 interpreter, this seems valid

```
>>> [] = ()
>>>
```

While this throws a SyntaxError

```
>>> () = []
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to ()
>>>
```

Why is the first statement valid and what does it mean ?

Why is the second one invalid ?

**dis** does not give a lot of informations:

```
dis.dis('[] = ()')   1           0 BUILD_TUPLE              0
              3 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          0
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Might be a bug, rather than intended behavior. I'm on 3.6.3 and `() = []` works on my machine.

Comment: Both work fine on Python 3.7.0

Comment: `()=[]` and `[]=()` both work fine in Python 3.7 when I try them (in that they do nothing).

Comment: Can confirm the behaviour for Python 2.7

Comment: Tried on python 3.5 and confirm the behavior.

Comment: In general that syntax is _supposed_ to work because of unpacking: you can assign to a tuple full of variables, and the variables receive the values unpacked from the right hand side of the assignment. It doesn't really mean anything for an empty tuple, so it's not that important whether it works or not.

Comment: The `SyntaxError` in earlier versions is a minor bug, see https://bugs.python.org/issue23275